# representation theory of two-step nilpotent Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Does anyone know of any good reference about the representation theory of two-step nilpotent Lie algebras, like whether their irreducible representations can be classified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all irreducible representations of a nilpotent Lie algebra are $1$-dimensional by Lie's theorem (over the complex numbers). For representation theory in general of nilpotent Lie algebras see also our article concerning  [Faithful Lie algebra representations of nilpotent Lie algebras](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_40_faithful_mod.pdf). For $2$-step nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension $n$ we can prove that there exists a faithful Lie algebra representation of dimension $n$. This is not true in general for higher-step nilpotent Lie algebras.